# Mix clickable row and unclickable row on slickgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

For my columns definition.

```
var columns = [
    {id: "label", name: "point", formatter:this.clickableFormatter,field: "point",width: 150},
```

then I add clickhander for it.

```
chart.addClickHandler(){
}
```

Also I use `clickableFormatter` for this.

```
clickableFormatter(row,cell,value,columnDef,dataContext){
  return "<span style='cursor:pointer;'>" + value + "</span>";
}
```

From these code. my table rows are clickable and I can show the user where is clickable by changing pointer.

However now I want to make one row unclickable.
(for example `total` row)

Is it possible to prevent click event for one low??
And is it possible to use another `formatter` for one row?

I gave the data from `for loop` and add `total` seperately.

```
for (var k = 0 ; k < data.length ;k++){       
    var temp = new Array();
    temp['id'] = data[k]['id'];
    temp['point'] = data[k]['point'];
    ret.push(temp);
}
 ret.push({ 
    'id' : "total",
    "point" : pointTotal,
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your formatter, you have access to the value of the cell, so if `value==='total'`, just return an empty string.

Also FYI, I don't think you need the `for` loop in your code (you could just leave it out entirely), unless you're using it to calculate the total, but you don't seem to be doing that.

If you think that you need it for creating the array objects, you're misunderstanding arrays in javascript, what you're actually setting is object properties, and it would be usual to initialise with `var temp = { };` rather than as Array.
It may not make sense at first, but everything in javascript is an object, including arrays and functions. So you can add object properties to anything.

```
somevar[numericVal] = x;    // set array element, somevar must be type Array
somevar['stringVal'] = x;   // set object property 'stringVal'
somevar.stringVal = x;      // identical to above line, different way of specifying
```

Comment: As you told, I can use value in formatter. It solves the problem. and for loop, I was stupid!! thank you very much!! However I am not sure why var temp ={} is better than Array(); it is because of memory usage??

Comment: Sorry, I can't find a link that explains it well. But in that loop you are using object properties. var temp = {}; declares an object, which you can set properties on. var temp = []; or var temp = Array[]; (the same) declare an array, which is also an object, so you can set object properties on them also. You just never use their actual array functionality.